# How to remove a commit from remote master branch?

Tags: git, github

How do I prepare my commit from my laptop to the remote github, so I can remove the commit from the remote easily if I want to? Will the pull request help?

-------------- UPDATE

This is what I normally do:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git merge --no-ff <my branch branched from master>
git push
```

Laster I realize that I have to remove 'my branch branched from master' from the master.

Comment: `so I can remove the commit from the remote easily if I want to` ... ideally you should not be removing the commit from the remote once it has been published there.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Two Alternatives that will keep the history intact:-

- Remove or fix the bad file in a new commit and push it to the remote repository. This is the most safe and natural way to fix any error.
- Revert the full commit, `git revert bbcdwe123efd`, sometimes you may want to undo whole commit with all changes. Reverting a commit means to create a new commit that undoes all changes that were made in the bad commit. Just like above, the bad commit remains there, but it no longer affects the the current master

  Also If you have direct access to the remote repo, you can Change its HEAD reference.`git update-ref HEAD HEAD^`(To remove last commit) or `git update-ref refs/heads/branch-name a12d48e2`

Comment: I updated the question with what I do. The revert will help in that situation?